# Spearman correlation from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Samples   GENE GEN1  GEN2 GEN3   GEN4 GEN5
Sample1     21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5
Sample2  21.0  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0
Sample3    22.8  108  5 3.85 2.32 18.6
```

What I pretend is to perform a spearman correlation using the column `GENE` vs each other columns, ie GENEvsGEN1, GENEvsGEN2, etc.
And obtain a table with the rho and p-values of each column (the results are invented):

```
             rho     p-value
GENEvsGEN1    0.01193936     0.34
GENEvsGEN2 0.0113436     0.034
```

I know I can obtain it individually using:

```
res2 <-cor.test(data$GENE, data$GEN1,  method = "spearman")
res2
```

But I have almost 5000 columns, so doing manually each one is not viable.

Any suggestions about how I can handle it?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop in order to store each comparison, as follows

```
### Initiating data
data <- data.frame(GENE=rnorm(100),
                   GEN1=rnorm(100),
                   GEN2=rnorm(100),
                   GEN3=rnorm(100))

### Initiating empty dataframe for storing results
matCorrSpearman <- data.frame(gene=paste("GENE vs ", colnames(data)[-1]), rho=rep(NA, ncol(data)-1), pvalue=NA)

### Storing results through a loop
for(i in 2:ncol(data)){
  res <- cor.test(data[, "GENE"], data[, i], method="spearman")
  matCorrSpearman$rho[i-1] <- res$estimate
  matCorrSpearman$pvalue[i-1] <- res$p.value
}

### Display results
matCorrSpearman
```

Results

```
           gene        rho    pvalue
1 GENE vs  GEN1 0.10882688 0.2806195
2 GENE vs  GEN2 0.05983798 0.5536572
3 GENE vs  GEN3 0.15259526 0.1294692
```

Comment: All the answers are perfect, but this one I found simple and smart. Thank you so much! It works great!

Answer (score 2):

An option could be using the [`corr.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/2.2.9/topics/corr.test) function from the `psych` package which makes it possible to have a matrix as input to compute the test with one column with all others like this:

```r
# Remove non numeric column
df = df[,-1]
# Correlation test
library(psych)
corr.test(df[, colnames(df) != "GENE"], df$GENE, method = 'spearman')
#> Warning in corr.test(df[, colnames(df) != "GENE"], df$GENE, method =
#> "spearman"): Number of subjects must be greater than 3 to find confidence
#> intervals.
#> Call:corr.test(x = df[, colnames(df) != "GENE"], y = df$GENE, method = "spearman")
#> Correlation matrix 
#>       [,1]
#> GEN1 -1.00
#> GEN2 -1.00
#> GEN3 -1.00
#> GEN4 -0.87
#> GEN5  0.87
#> Sample Size 
#> [1] 3
#> These are the unadjusted probability values.
#>   The probability values  adjusted for multiple tests are in the p.adj object. 
#>      [,1]
#> GEN1 0.00
#> GEN2 0.00
#> GEN3 0.00
#> GEN4 0.33
#> GEN5 0.33
#> 
#>  To see confidence intervals of the correlations, print with the short=FALSE option
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is one potential solution using [`expand.grid()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/expand.grid) to generate the different combination of variables (e.g. GENE,GEN1 & GENE,GEN2 etc), then using [`pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) from the purrr package to evaluate each of the combinations. The cor.test function requires two numeric vectors as input, so you can use [`pull()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) to extract the 'variables of interest' from the dataframe and pass them to the function. Then, the ouput is formatted using [`tidy()`](https://generics.r-lib.org/reference/tidy.html) from the broom package, and the required columns are selected.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- read.table(text = "Samples   GENE GEN1  GEN2 GEN3   GEN4 GEN5
Sample1     21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5
Sample2  21.0  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0
Sample3    22.8  108  5 3.85 2.32 18.6",
header = TRUE)

groupings <- expand.grid("GENE", names(df)[-c(1,2)])
groupings
#>   Var1 Var2
#> 1 GENE GEN1
#> 2 GENE GEN2
#> 3 GENE GEN3
#> 4 GENE GEN4
#> 5 GENE GEN5

# cor.test requires two numeric vectors,
# so a workaround with pmap() is to use pull()
result <- pmap(groupings, ~cor.test(df %>% pull(.x),
                                    df %>% pull(.y),
                                    method = "spearman")) %>% 
  map_df(tidy) %>%
  cbind(groupings, .) %>%
  rename("rho" = "estimate") %>%
  select(Var1, Var2, rho, p.value)

result
#>   Var1 Var2        rho   p.value
#> 1 GENE GEN1 -1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 2 GENE GEN2 -1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 3 GENE GEN3 -1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 4 GENE GEN4 -0.8660254 0.3333333
#> 5 GENE GEN5  0.8660254 0.3333333
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>